# Expanding the classes - CSS/HTML convention

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I have the simple table generated by js and I'd like to change some properties of columns and rows like background color, width statically. I can extend the row and col classes directly in CSS file or do it in html.

Example (CSS approach):

HTML:

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="foo"></div>
                <div class="col"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

> ...
>
> .col, .foo {
>       display: table-row;
>       height: 20px; }
>
> .foo { background: red; width: 100px; }
>
> ...

Example (html approach):

HTML:

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col foo"></div>
                <div class="col"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

> ...
>
> .col {
>       display: table-row;
>       height: 20px; }
>
> .foo { background: red; width: 100px; }
>
> ...

In my opinion the second approach is more convenient for dynamically changing elements rather then static ones. However the first one obscures the structure of the html which can cause some problems with understanding the javascript. My question is which approach would be better in this case?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here, but you ask "the second approach is good, however the first is bad, so which one is better"? (FWIW, I'd agree with you that the second is better.)

Comment: I just mentioned that the second one is better for dynamically changing elements (my html code is the static one).